# I created a generic reducer for the state , when should it be used and when should it not be used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a redux store. To change the data in the store, the typical way is to create an action, actionCreator, a reducer and then dispatch the action.
For a small to medium sized app, it looks like an overkill to change at so many place to reflect such changes. So I created a generic reducer which looks something like this :

```
// here state is a copy of actual state, so I can mutate it directly

    const reducer = ( state, action) => {
      if(action.type == 'SETTER'){
       try{
            return assign(state, action.data.target, action.data.value )
        }
        catch(err){
            console.log('WARNING: the key wasn\'t valid', err)
        }
      }
      return state;

    }
```

this `assign` method goes like this:

```
const assign = (obj, prop, value) => {
    if (typeof prop === "string")
        prop = prop.split(".");

    if (prop.length > 1) {
        var e = prop.shift();
        assign(obj[e] , prop, value);
    } else
        obj[prop[0]] = value;
  return obj
}
```

Then I have a a generic action dispatcher and a container component, which allow me to do something like this :

```
containerComponent.set( 'user.name', 'Roy' )
containerComponent.set( 'order.receiver.address', 'N/A')
```

The action which fires when `set` is called on the containerComponent looks like this :

```
{
  type : 'SETTER',
  data : {
    target : 'user.name',
    value : 'Roy'
  }
}
```

As you can see, this generic reducer allows me to never write a reducer again, but I am still dispatching an action whenever state changes, so no violation of any of the core principles of redux.

Are there any minor/major shortcomings in this approach, especially in terms of performance? And also, where do you find this approach to be useful.

Comment: You are mutating your state. Redux, specifically React-Redux, checks references to determine whether an object has changed, so it knows whether to update. Your `assign` method mutates state.

Comment: @dashnote The object being mutated is a copy of the state and not the actual state object. I'm using immerjs for this purpose. And the updates occur without any issue whenever state changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you noted quite right, Redux requires you to implement multiple layers of indirection between the point where something in your application happens, and the point where the store is actually updated to reflect this event.

This is by design.

Global state generally creates the problem that it can be changed arbitrarily from anywhere in your application, without a simple way of understanding how or why. And yes, a Redux store is effectively global state.

By separating the questions of *what happened* (as represented by an action and described by the action's payload) from *how does that affect the global state* (as defined by the reducer), Redux removes this issue to a certain degree. Instead of allowing arbitrary changes to the global state, only certain, very specific combinations of changes can be made, triggered by well-defined events that in the best case come with enough semantic information attached to them to enable tracing them back to their origin.

By undermining this core idea of Redux by creating a single pair of generic action and reducer, you loose one of the core advantages of Redux, and are left with a set of indirections and abstractions between your components and the store that don't really bring you any significant benefits.

It is common wisdom that code that doesn't create value is code best deleted. In my mind, you may be much better off not using Redux and simply using component state instead rather than using a crippled implementation of Redux.

---

An interesting read regarding this topic from Dan Abramov, who created Redux: [You might not need Redux](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367).

Comment: thanks for the answer. I understand the point you made. One of the advantages of state management via redux vs using component state is the cross-communication among components.  By using the above approach, I am able to change the state in redux at same ease as the component state, plus I can easily communicate amongst the components, I can still track when did the state change using debug tools (thus can still do the 'time travel in redux' to debug issues, if any). So, my question is, apart from losing explicitness, are there some major performance issues as well, with the code above?

Comment: In short, there are no major performance issues. (The size of a JS callstack is almost never a performance bottleneck in most JS apps anyway.) Though if you're looking for the "single source of data" functionality that redux uses, it's not too hard to implement that on your own, by putting a simple JS object in the context and manipulating it wherever you want to. The _value_ of Redux is the abstraction, which is what @Timo gets at in his answer. If you don't want that value, and you're concerned about performance, then at that point you might as well implement a global store yourself.

Comment: I should add, though, that the value of the abstraction is not its explicitness, it's about [separation of concerns](http://wiki.c2.com/?SeparationOfConcerns) and the [single responsibility principle](http://wiki.c2.com/?SingleResponsibilityPrinciple), as applied to functional programming. The abstraction allows you to refactor your actions, reducers, and components separately; with your `assign` function, you distribute that logic to your whole system, making your application harder to change.

Answer (score 0):

Timo's answer does a good job explaining why your implementation sort of goes against a lot of the principles of Redux. I would just add that you might find [Mobx](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx) interesting. I think it more closely resembles the sort of state management you're trying to get.

Answer (score 0):

This function (assign called by reducer) is not according Redux rules, this is not immutable 'pure' function because mutate state.

Test:

```
const assign = (obj, prop, value) => {
  if (typeof prop === "string")
    prop = prop.split(".");

  if (prop.length > 1) {
    var e = prop.shift();
    assign(obj[e], prop, value);
  } else
    obj[prop[0]] = value;

  return obj
}

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type == 'SETTER') {
    try {
      return assign(state, action.data.target, action.data.value)
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log('WARNING: the key wasn\'t valid', err)
    }
  }
  return state;
}

const testReducer = () => {
  const user = {
    id: 0,
    name: ''
  };
  const action = {
    type: 'SETTER',
    data: {
      target: 'name',
      value: 'Roy'
    }
  };

  console.log('user before: ', user);
  reducer(user, action);
  console.log('user after: ', user);

};

testReducer();
```

Test results:

```
user before:  { id: 0, name: '' }
user after:  { id: 0, name: 'Roy' }
```

Easiest fix:

```
const assign = (obj, prop, value) => {
  var tempObj = Object.assign({}, obj);

  if (typeof prop === "string")
    prop = prop.split(".");

  if (prop.length > 1) {
    var e = prop.shift();
    assign(tempObj[e], prop, value);
  } else
    tempObj[prop[0]] = value;

  return tempObj
}
```

**EDIT**

Fix without copy the values of the state object to temp target object:

```
const assign = (obj, prop, value) => {
  if (typeof prop === "string")
    prop = prop.split(".");

  if (prop.length > 1) {
    var e = prop.shift();
    assign(obj[e], prop, value);
  } else {
    return {
      ...obj,
      [prop[0]]: value
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: please refer to the question detail, I have mentioned that the 'state' object is not actual state object but a copy of the state. So we can directly mutate it. In short, it's similar (but optimised) to Object.assign part you have done in the assign method, but it's happening at higher level

Comment: @AnishK. A copy of the state is a quite bad solution. Please view edited response.

Comment: it's not really a simple clone using Object.assign(). Rather I am using immerJS which is quite performant in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Reducer are now simple functions and can be easily reuse

```
const getData = (state, action) => {
    return {...state, data: state.data.concat(action.payload)};
};

const removeLast = (state) => {
    return {...state, data: state.data.filter(x=>x !== state.data[state.data.length-1])};
}
```

Action type and reducer function are now declared in an array

```
const actions = [
    {type: 'GET_DATA', reducer: getData},
    {type: 'REMOVE_LAST', reducer: removeLast},
    {type: 'REMOVE_FIRST', reducer: removeFirst},
    {type: 'REMOVE_ALL', reducer: removeAll},
    {type: 'REMOVE_BY_INDEX', reducer: removeByIndex}
];
```

Initial state for the reducer

```
const initialState = {
    data: []
}
```

actionGenerators creates an unique Id using Symbol and assign that Id to actions and reducer function.

```
const actionGenerators = (actions) => {
    return actions.reduce((a,c)=>{
        const id = Symbol(c.type);   
        a.actions = {...a.actions, [c.type]: id};
        a.reducer = a.reducer ? a.reducer.concat({id, reducer: c.reducer}) : [{id, reducer: c.reducer}];
        return a;
    },{});
}
```

reducerGenerators is a generic reducer creator.

```
const reducerGenerators = (initialState, reducer) => {
    return (state = initialState, action) => {
        const found = reducer.find(x=>x.id === action.type);
        return found ? found.reducer(state, action) : state;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
const actionsReducerCreator = actionGenerators(actions);
const store = createStore(reducerGenerators(initialState, actionsReducerCreator.reducer));
const {GET_DATA} = actionsReducerCreator.actions;
store.dispatch({type: GET_DATA});
```

I have implemented this in my todo application on my github
[Redux-Reducer-Generator](https://github.com/Thuthinh/Redux-Reducer-Generator)